# How to properly configure DateTime axis for Highcharts on Android?

Tags: java, android, highcharts

I currently have a bubble chart working in my app but I am having some issues getting the datetime axis to work properly. I have looked at the documentation provided by Highcharts, but that made me a little more confused...

I am trying to have it display a date, say 06/25/2020, and so on. In another instance, I am just looking to display the days of the week.

My date is stored in a string using the format "MM/dd/yyyy", from there I used DateFormat and converted the string to a Date. From there I used rdate.getTime() and passed this into my data points.

```
HIXAxis xaxis = new HIXAxis();
        xaxis.setGridLineWidth(1);
        xaxis.setType("datetime");

String str_recordDate = r.getDate();
DateFormat dFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
rDate = (Date)dFormatter.parse(str_recordDate);

 Number[][] series1Data = new Number[][] {
                {rDate.getTime(), 20, 63}};
```

[Example output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFozK.png)

I am decently new to highcharts and just looking for some advice to get in the right direction. Any help with my problem would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this config:

```
HIXAxis axis = new HIXAxis();
axis.setType("datetime");
axis.setDateTimeLabelFormats(new HIDateTimeLabelFormats());
axis.getDateTimeLabelFormats().setDay(new HIDay());
axis.getDateTimeLabelFormats().getDay().setMain("%e of %b"); // this will give e.g.: 1 of Jan
options.setXAxis(new ArrayList<>(Collections.singletonList(axis)));
```

Additionally, you can try to do something like this:

```
series.setPointStart(new Date(99,0,1).getTime()); // starting from 1.1.1999
series.setPointInterval(24 * 3600 * 1000); // one day
```